# How to wait until speech is finished inside Loop?

Tags: javascript, wait, text-to-speech

I would like to halt/wait the for-loop until the `window.speechSynthesis.speak(audio)` finishes reading the text, then go to next iteration. I have below code:

```
 var all = "Oak is strong and also gives shade \n \
    Cats and dogs each hate the other \n \
    The pipe began to rust while new \n Bye."


 sentences = all.split('\n')
      for (i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        sentence = sentences[i]
        console.log(sentences[i]);
        audio = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(sentence)
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(audio)
         }
```

Now what I want is that, once each `sentences[i]` is printed. The next `sentences[i]` will not be printed until   `window.speechSynthesis.speak(audio)` is finished, once the speech is finished then the `sentences[i]`  will be printed for the next iteration.

So how can I make the loop wait until a function is not finished?

**Note:** I can make it wait for a constant time, but I want a dynamic wait, i.e. the wait should be as long as`window.speechSynthesis.speak(audio)` takes time to finish the text.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` API there is an `onend` event what you can play with ([SpeechSynthesisUtterance: end event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/end_event)).

So I guess you can add an event listener to `onend` where you need to call the next iteration's code. One good technique is to use `Promise` in asynchronous cases to wait until a callback finishes. I have created a working example for the above case from your question:

```
(function() {
  play();

  async function play() {
    let all = "Oak is strong and also gives shade \n \
              Cats and dogs each hate the other \n \
              The pipe began to rust while new \n Bye.";

    sentences = all.split('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
      await getNextAudio(sentences[i]);
    }

    async function getNextAudio(sentence) {
      console.log(sentence);
      let audio = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(sentence);
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(audio);

      return new Promise(resolve => {
        audio.onend = resolve;
      });
    } 
  }
})();
```

If you are interested in more details, please go for the following links to read further:

1. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
2. [SpeechSynthesis.speak()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak)
3. [SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onend)
4. [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

The solution works just like charm, hope this helps!

Comment: +1

I built an online demo using this as base code here.  I added chopping by words, letters, etc.

https://tombyrer.github.io/web-speech-synth-segmented/

Comment: @tomByrer That's a nice one, good representation for the scenario!

Answer (score 2):

There's also an onstart event which you could use like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
  const sentence = sentences[i];
  const audio = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(sentence);
  audio.onstart = () => console.log(audio.text);
  speechSynthesis.speak(audio);
}
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
for (const sentence of sentences) {
  const audio = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(sentence);
  audio.onstart = () => console.log(audio.text);
  speechSynthesis.speak(audio);
}
```

PS you could amend the top of your code to use const (or let) instead of var like this:

```
const all = "Oak is strong and also gives shade \n \
    Cats and dogs each hate the other \n \
    The pipe began to rust while new \n Bye.";
const sentences = all.split('\n');
```

Comment: What if I want to use ``Word_Reader(audio.text);``  instead of ``console.log(audio.text);`` ?? the function is as described below - ``function Word_Reader(word) {
 
for (k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {


let audio_word = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(word[k]);

console.log(audio_word.text);
speechSynthesis.speak(audio_word);


}
} ``  , I tried it didn't work, can you help?

Comment: @Andrew I think it's best to write a new question because from these small comments it will take time to understand what you want e.g. is the Word_Reader function going inside the for loop?, is the purpose to say the sentence then each letter within that sentence? and if not what?, what didn't work?, what's your complete code?, etc.