# Pause loop and wait for events before moving to next iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

all:

I have this loop in which I have a timeout in to try and pause an iteration while an animation and sound finish before it moves on to the next iteration, however; I'm finding that i is not increased when it hits the timeout anonymous function and causes an infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < gamePattern.length - 1) {
  console.log(i);
  buttonAnimation(gamePattern[i]);
  buttonSound(gamePattern[i]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    i++;
  }, 400);
}
```

I was thinking of trying to set it up with promises, but I don't feel that would actually pause the iteration like I though. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Kevin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait until speech is finished inside Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049491/how-to-wait-until-speech-is-finished-inside-loop)

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this. A straigthforward way is to use a `for` loop instead and use a formula like `i * 400` for the timeout delay.

Answer (score 0):

Always use let, const. var is old and error prone.

using async/await with promises you can acheive the code waiting timing between iterations

```
const wait = (cb, time) => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb();
      res();
    }, time)
  })
}

async function doSomeThing(){
  let i = 0;

  while(i < gamePattern.length-1){
    console.log(i);
    buttonAnimation(gamePattern[i]);
    buttonSound(gamePattern[i]);
    await wait(() => {i++;}, 400)
  }
}
doSomeThing()
```

Comment: why not just `const wait = time => new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, time); });` and then `await wait(400); i++;` You shouldn't need a callback for a function that returns a promise...